# How to sample two textures onto the same object?

Tags: c++, graphics, directx-11

I have to reproduce an effect which consists of combining two textures (tiles + coin) to achieve the following:

[image: Goal]

The best result I achieved so far:

[image: Result]

[Visual Studio Solution to reproduce the problem](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/li8jzmal4bj97a5/AAC1vBojWnQgCNLs1yneW2ova?dl=0)

The link above will take you to the project and here what I tried to do in the pixel shader:

```
float4 PS(PS_INPUT input) : SV_Target
{
    float4 color1;
    float4 color2;
    float4 blendColor;


    // Get the pixel color from the first texture.
    color1 = texTile.Sample(samLinear, input.Tex) * vMeshColor;

    // Get the pixel color from the second texture.
    color2 = texCoin.Sample(samLinear, input.Tex) * vMeshColor;

    // Blend the two pixels together and multiply by the gamma value.
    blendColor = color1 * color2;

    // Saturate the final color.
    blendColor = saturate(blendColor);

    return blendColor;
}
```

But it does not seem the right way of doing this.
Which aproach should I take to have the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well firstly you are blending them but not blending using an alpha-mask, when the example image seems to have been blended with an alpha-mask.

An example could be something like below; provided the coin has got an alpha-channel.
(Otherwise you'll have to calculate an alpha or add one in an image editing software.

```
    float3 blend(float4 CoinTex, float3 GridTex)
    {
         // Inverse of alpha, to get the area around the coin
         // Alpha spans from [0,1] so the expression below would suffice
         float1 inverseAlpha = (1 - CoinTex.a);

         float3 blendedTex = 0;
         
         // If-else that is evaluated to decide how they'll be overlayed
         if (inverseAlpha > 0.0 ){
             blendedTex = GridTex.rgb;
         } else {blendedTex = CoinTex.rgb;}

         return blendedTex;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ario Amin! I applied what you suggested and it works.

Comment: Glad to be of help! 
I suggest checking out: https://github.com/patriciogonzalezvivo/thebookofshaders

It is a great W.I.P. resource when starting out and the github has to chapter 15 atleast.

Steps to clone the repo and installing it for offline access: 
https://thebookofshaders.com/appendix/00/